# Transition effect applied to nested class is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to hover on one div to make another nested div appear, but the transition-delay doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas?

```
 .vm:hover > .sparkline {
        position: relative; 
        top: -10em;
        left: 10em;
        width: 640px; 
        height: 480px;
        background-image: url(../images/sparkline.png);
        transition-delay: 3s;
      }
```

Comment: What exactly are you changing ? share your html too.. Or a fiddle maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is you need to deside which attribute will be affected by transition and define its values different for normal and hovered state. If you want to make div appear, then this attribute is either `opacity` or `display`.

```
.vm > .sparkline {
    position: relative; 
    top: -10em;
    left: 10em;
    width: 640px; 
    height: 480px;
    background-image: url('../images/sparkline.png');
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease 3s;
}
.vm:hover > .sparkline {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

in the line `transition: opacity 1s ease 3s;` 3s - is a `transition-delay` parameter.